# Service Unavaliable

Tags: error

I downloaded Lamp and am trying to install Craft CMS, but I keep getting a "Service Unavailable- Our site is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later." In the log file it printed the following:

```
******************************************************************************************************
2016/06/25 22:39:51 [error] [exception.Craft\HttpException.503] exception 'Craft\HttpException' in /var/www/html/test_craft/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php:798
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/test_craft/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(203): Craft\WebApp->_processInstallRequest()
#1 /var/www/html/test_craft/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(185): Craft\WebApp->processRequest()
#2 /var/www/html/test_craft/craft/app/index.php(62): CApplication->run()
#3 /var/www/html/public/index.php(19): require_once('/var/www/html/t...')
#4 {main}
REQUEST_URI=/public/
---

******************************************************************************************************
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll get that message if Craft isn't installed and you hit the front-end of the site.

You'll want to load the control panel for the installer to trigger as noted in [Step 5](https://craftcms.com/docs/installing#step-5-run-the-installer) of the install docs.

Comment: when I do localhost/public/admin or localhost/admin I get a 404. What is the url to set it up? Thanks!

Comment: Actually got it: http://localhost/public/index.php/admin

Comment: Glad you're up and running!